# Need recommendation for a beginner-friendly philosophy forum

Tags: discussion

As you may or may not have seen, a metaphysics problem has long been plaguing me, and while I asked that question on this site, the ensuing answers really demanded a longer form of back and forth for me to achieve results, which the stack exchange format is ideally suited for.

I am thinking the best format for the conversation I would like to have is a forum, that welcomes questions from beginners but has kind people who know a lot about philosophy and can help someone like me get a little further with a back and forth threaded journey of thoughts on a particular topic. (I know that is *somewhat* possible here with comments, but not only do comments have a very limited character count, you can't format them with whitespace or paragraphs.)

Do please hear this though: I am **not** being critical of stack exchange **at all**, it is perfect for it's purpose. In fact, this is me taking **advantage** of what stack exchange can do, which is to help me leverage the experience of others to answers a specific question with a definite answer. And this time what I am seeking help finding is a place to go and have conversations on topics where the longer form nature of the inquiry is not well suited to stack exchange.

Thanks.

Comment: It would be nice to have a philosophical forum one could point to because many "questions" here are really discussion invitations, and more suitable for forum format. But... I don't know of one.

Comment: @sindyr: conifold is spot on; unfortunately I too don't know of one; possibly, in the future someone might be enterprising enough to start a site based around readings, and moderated discussions; unfortunately that doesn't help you now.

Comment: You could try inviting people to chat.

Comment: This is about as a neutral a philosophy venue as you can reasonably expect to exist. Many just exist to promulgate some sort of ideology.

Comment: @NeilMeyer I agree that this is a very neutral venue, it just limits discourse to a question and answer format - for example, right now I only have 452 characters left and dropping. I thought I forum format would be a better fit for the back and forth I am looking for on a specific inquiry I have.  Thanks.

Comment: This is the best discussion group of which I am aware https://groups.yahoo.com/neo/groups/fallible-ideas/info

Answer (score 6):

Try www.reddit.com/r/askphilosophy

/r/askphilosophy is staffed by a panel of grad students and professors in philosophy.  In practice there are about a dozen active grad students, and 3-4 active profs, so there's usually someone who can cover most areas of philosophy if the question isn't too niche. Answers are generally fair and well-informed, and if the question isn't posed quite right or makes some presumptions you should think twice about, they'll generally help you there too.

reddit formatting is also very easy to learn.

Answer (score 6):

There's quite an active philosophy forum at http://forums.philosophyforums.com/ .  I can't vouch for how beginner-friendly it is.  The last time I was active there, I wasn't a big fan of what I perceived as a strong structural bias towards modern analytic philosophy, but that was many years ago, and a quick glance seems to suggest that the entire site's organization has changed since them.

Answer (score -1):

### Answer

As mentioned above, you are welcome to go to the [Symposium](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/538/the-symposium) which is the PhilSE chat room and engage a user directly by starting your question with the tag @USERNAME. Why we don't have a sister site for posting dialectical questions is a bit puzzling to me since we have so many users try. Certainly such a sister site would draw considerable traffic.